# How to extract the bounding box of a model in Blender?

Tags: blender, bounding-box, object-detection

I am using Blender to render a model. The model is captured by the camera whose placement changes. Then I write the image to a file. How do I find the bounding box in the image so that this box can be used for annotation useful in training object detection models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every object in blender has a [bound_box property](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.bound_box), this is in simple axis min/max not an optimal rotated bounding box. Note that non-renderable objects will show a zero size bound_box, such as empty, camera, light, lattice, armature.

Depending on the accuracy or time trade-offs you want to make, you can translate the points in the bound_box or each object vertex, to a rendered image co-ordinate as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1008/935). By translating each vertex you can create a region defining the outline of the object or you can just use min/max to create a simple bounding box to surround it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158236) answer is better suited for the task at hand (with 2.8 updates).